# Conditional expectation on the union of two events

Tags: conditional-expectation

Is there any property to simplify a conditional expectation of the form:

$\mathbb{E}[A| B\cup C]$

In my particular case, $A$ and $B$ are independent, so I would like to use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[A|B]=\mathbb{E}[A]$

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: It is uncommon to write $\mathbb E[A\mid B\cup C]$ if we are dealing with events.